# How to stream a bool value from firestore to flutter using riverpod

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I am using flutter 3.16.9 latest and am working on a chat application for my github. I want to display a user typing indicator when the other user is typing.

While doing so i get stuck on a problem where i don't know how to return a bool value.

This is code i am using right now.

```
final isUserTyping = StreamProvider.family<bool, ChatRoomModelData>((ref, c) {
  
  final stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('chat_room')
      .doc(c.roomId)
      .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
      .map((snapshot) =>
          snapshot.data()?['members_data'][c.otherUserId]['isTyping'] ?? false);


  return stream as Stream<bool>;
});
```

And this is my consumer widget code

```
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, child) {

    ChatRoomModelData modelData = ChatRoomModelData(
      roomId: chatService.roomIdGen(
        widget.receiverId,
        widget.senderId,
      ),
      userId: widget.senderId,
      otherUserId: widget.receiverId,
    );

    final typingStream = ref.watch(
      isUserTyping(modelData),
    );

    return typingStream.when(
      data: (data) {
        return Text(data.toString());
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) {
        return const Text(
          'Error',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            letterSpacing: 1,
          ),
        );
      },
      loading: () {
        return const Text(
          'Loading ...',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            letterSpacing: 1,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
),
```

Now after all of this it show me error widget this and when i print

```
print(typingStream.hasValue);
```

it return false.

but when i do the same in my riverpod code and check if the print snapshot it print the current value from firestore and update it self when i change my value in firestore.

i seriously dont know where the problem is or how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When using a StreamProvider, it must be used with async*, and stream data have to be passed with yield, not return.

And I highly recommend you use [code generator](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation).

```
@riverpod
Stream<bool> isUserTyping(IsUserTypingRef ref,
    {required ChatRoomModelData c}) async* {
  // Add your stream.

  yield stream as bool;
}

class Consumer extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ChatRoomModelData modelData = ChatRoomModelData(
      roomId: chatService.roomIdGen(
        receiverId,
        senderId,
      ),
      userId: senderId,
      otherUserId: receiverId,
    );

    AsyncValue<bool> value = ref.watch(IsUserTypingProvider(c: modelData));

    return switch (value) {
      AsyncValue(:final value?) => Text(value.toString()),
      AsyncValue(:final error?) => const Text(
          'Error',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            letterSpacing: 1,
          ),
        ),
      _ => const Text(
          'Loading ...',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            letterSpacing: 1,
          ),
        ),
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't active I have exams going on I'm outside of my city without my laptop so I'll response and let you know if this code works or not... Anyways thankyou for your response..